# Rail6-Webpack jQuery configuration for materialize navbar Dropdown working 0

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, materialize

Rail6-Webpack jQuery configuration for navbar Dropdown working
0
Ferran · Lecture 42 · a minute ago
Rails version             6.0.2.2

Ruby version              ruby 2.7.1

## app/javascript/packs/javascript.js

require("@rails/ujs").start()

require("turbolinks").start()

require("@rails/activestorage").start()

require("channels")

require("jquery")

import '../css/application'

import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize'

import 'material-design-icons'

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

$(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();

})
```

## app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Usuari<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
```

$ yarn add jquery

## config/webpack/environment.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',

  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({

    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',

    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'

  })

)
```

Comment: What exactly the problem is?

Comment: Was! I could fix webpack-materalize-jquery problems based on doing this additions for the navbar dropdown. I posted the solution.